# Unable to add many through relation in Redmine plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am developing a plugin for Redmine. I want to add a model called Quote, and a join model called QuoteIssue.

*db/migrations/001_create_quotes.rb*

```
class CreateQuotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :quotes do |t|
      t.references :project, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

*db/migrations/002_create_quote_issues.rb*

```
class CreateQuoteIssues < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :quote_issues do |t|
      t.belongs_to :quote, index: true
      t.belongs_to :issue, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

*app/models/quote.rb*

```
class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :project
    has_many :quote_issues
    has_many :issues, :through => :quote_issues
end
```

*app/models/quote_issue.rb*

```
class QuoteIssue < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :quote
    belongs_to :issue
end
```

I have even patched Issue to add the relation:

*lib/issue_patch.rb*

```
require_dependency 'issue'

module IssuePatch
    def self.include(base)
        base.extend(ClassMethods)
        base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)

        base.class_eval do
            has_many :quote_issues
            has_many :quotes, :through => :quote_issues
        end
    end

    module ClassMethods
    end

    module InstanceMethods
    end
end

Issue.send(:include, IssuePatch)
```

So everything has been made [according to the docs I read](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Now even if the relation from quote to issues is fairly obvious, rails can't figure it out:

```
Quote.create().issues
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `quotes` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2017-05-24 00:47:01', '2017-05-24 00:47:01')
   (7.5ms)  COMMIT
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) "issue" or :issues in model QuoteIssue. Try 'has_many :issues, :through => :quote_issues, :source => <name>'. Is it one of ?
```

There isn't any suggestion before the question mark.

Is it because I did not follow the rails doc properly, or is it an edge case for Redmine that I need to take care of?

Server/versions info:

- Debian 8
- ruby 2.1.5p273
- rails 4.2.7.1
- Redmine empty installation (e.g. no other plugin) v3.3.3.stable

Comment: You haven't specified which version or Rails/Redmine are you working with. Also check if there is something else patching Issue which might create ambiguity.

Comment: You're right! I've added the information to the question. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: This looks like a spelling error... ":trough" should be ":through"

Comment: Nice catch! Dear god! I have fixed it but the error message remains. I have tested the other way around, like `Issue.first.quotes` and it yields `undefined method 'quotes' for #<Issue:0x00000004d6fc00>`; this makes me wonder if my patch to `Issue` worked or not. I'll work on this.

Comment: Did you try has_many :issues, :through => :quote_issues, :source => :issue ?

Comment: @Nanego: yes. Didn't work.

Comment: Weird issue. Could you share your complete code source, on github maybe? You should also check your init.rb file.

Comment: @Nanego: please check bicou.net/rqi.tar.bz2